# How to Fix "Argument of type is not Iterable" Python?

Tags: python

I'm just experimenting and testing code and I can't seem to find a way to solve this, I have looked at other people's problems and I still can't seem to fix it.

Code:

```
ASD = "Noice! Ye got it."
ZXC = "Rip, you suck"

import random
xyz =(random.randrange(1, 10))
if 7 not in xyz:
  print("ASD")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

`int` doesn't work with the concept of `in` because an `int`, by nature, is not iterable. What you're looking for is just a straight comparison.

```
xyz =(random.randrange(1, 10))
if xyz != 7:
  print("ASD")
```

Comment: "`int` doesn't work with the concept of `in`". That's not quite correct. For example, `1 in [1,2,3]` works just fine. It's more correct to say that an `int` doesn't work on the *right-hand* side of the `in` operator, since that side *does* have to be an iterable.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that `xyz` is an int so you cannot interate on it with `in`.
As far as I understand what you're trying to do, you just need to compare `xyz` to `7`:

```
if xyz != 7:
    print(ASD)
```

And be carefull, you must `print(ASD)` and not `print("ASD")`.